# Custom Polymer element appears in the DOM, but does not give content in symfony project

Tags: javascript, php, polymer-1.0, symfony

Element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">

<dom-module id="app-index">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            h1 {
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
        <!--body is here-->
        <!--<app-drawer-layout>-->
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <span>test</span>
        <!--</app-drawer-layout>-->
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'app-index'
        });

    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Twig index:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{%  block links %}
    <link rel="import" href="../../../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <script src="../../../../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../../../../web/js/elements/app-index.html">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <app-index></app-index>
{% endblock %}
```

And the base twig file is nothing exciting, just the default from starting a symfony project.

Now the issue I am having is that I can display the page without errors, but the h1 and the span from the element do not appear.  I use the chrome dev tools and see the  tag  and when I hover over it I get a size of 0x0.  I can't figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's a path issue.
The link in HTML shows:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

But in your twig you have:

```
<link rel="import "href="../../../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

Notice the missing "**../**". Maybe you specified the wrong directory path somewhere?

I would suggest using FireFox to debug, I find it has much better tools available. Also in FireFox if you right-click on the page and select "inspect element", then go to the "Network" tab; then reload your page, you'll see if your scripts are loading correctly (usually an error is shown).